Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS Active directory Authentication
I am complete newbie with Linux and Ubuntu flavour , I have used it in the past without joining our windows local active directory and understand the basic syntax for running commands in terminal.
As a school we are currently in the process of converting a load of our lowish spec devices to run Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS.
From my basic research and understanding Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS doesn't support Azure AD login authentication as the module only supports Azure AD User Authentication is only included in Ubuntu 23.04 and 23.10.
So that only leaves me with Active directory authentication for 24.04
What's the best and easiest way of setting this up to connect to our local active directory?
Will setting up a Ubuntu Server Relay for authentication be more efficient?
Thanks
